# Fiduciary Responsibility of an RIA

Tags: legal, financial-advisor, liability

I'm currently an investment advisor with my own RIA sand I was approached by a company to do live streams talking about trade ideas and investments. They charge a subscription to their viewers and I receive compensation from the company. Since I am a registered advisor, is there any liability or risk I should be aware of that isn't apparent here? I would like to know if this type of role requires me to act as a fiduciary and if so, whether I am able to do so.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because isn't a question about personal finance or investing from an individual's perspective.